# How can I get hardware schematics for Mac computers?

Tags: mac

I'd really like to have hardware schematics (circuit diagrams for motherboards etc.) for Mac computers, as they might help me to repair them.

Any clues as to how can I get them?

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.apple-schematic.se/ This Website Would Help and Please Tell your Model for which you want schematic .

Answer (score 0):

Apple publishes repair manuals for new hardware and official parts and tools orders are also available.

- https://support.apple.com/manuals/Repair
- https://www.selfservicerepair.com/home

Circuit diagrams will need to be generated outside Apple. [Their “repair manifesto” paper explains in detail](https://support.apple.com/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/otherassets/programs/Expanding_Access_to_Service_and_Repairs.pdf) how they arrived at a decades-long service swap philosophy with repair depots doing all board level repairs and technicians doing board level swaps.

> Boards are packed with many small components necessary for the device’s proper functioning. For example, ball grid array (BGA) parts require specialized equipment for their repair that is restricted to factory or advanced repair environments due to its cost and complexity.